# Azure Functions func host start Error: "The gRPC binary module was not installed."

Tags: npm, azure-functions

yesterday the VS Code informed me to update **azure-functions-core-tools** and after updating it, this error was displayed to me after I ran "func host start" :

`Couldn't require bundle, falling back to Worker.js. Error: The gRPC binary module was not installed.This may be fixed by running "npm rebuild"`

any idea on how to fix this?I tried npm rebuild and it does not worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error often indicates that the `grpc` library was installed for a platform that is different from the one it is running on. The solution is to run `npm install` with extra arguments that describe the platform the library will run on. These options are described in the [`node-pre-gyp` README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pre-gyp).

For example, to install grpc for use on Node 10.0.0 on a 64-bit Linux that is not Alpine Linux, you can use the following command:

```
npm install --target=10.0.0 --target_arch=x64 --target_platform=linux --target_libc=glibc
```

Note: the `target_libc` option should be omitted for platforms other than Linux.

Answer (score 0):

after 2 hours, installing x86 version of  **azure-functions-core-tools**  resolved the error. but this may not be the best solution.